Function from $ℕ$ to a non-prime finite field, compatible with addition, and invertible for small values
Let $n$ be some positive integer and $_q$ a finite field. I am looking for (sufficient and/or necessary) conditions on $_q$ for the existence of a map $φ:ℕ→_q$ that satisfies the following conditions:

For any $i$, $j\in\{1,…,n\}$, $φ(i+j) = φ(i) + φ(j)$;
For any $k$, $ℓ\in\{2, …, 2n\}$, $φ(k) = φ(ℓ) \implies k = ℓ$.

Intuitively, this means that from a value $φ(i+j)$, one can recover the sum $i+j$ (but not, of course, the values $i$ and $j$ that are not unique).
Partial answers

If $q ≥ 2n-1$ is a prime, we can simply take $φ(i) = i\bmod q$ (the image of $i$ in $_q$).

If $q < 2n-1$, there are more elements in $\{2, …, 2n\}$ than in $_q$, so $φ$ cannot exist.


More precise question:
Is it possible to construct $φ$ for some non-prime fields $_q$, provided $q$ is large enough?

The first condition forces $\varphi(i) = i \varphi(1)$ so you are just taking some $\varphi(1) \in \mathbb{F}_q$ and repeatedly adding it to itself. This forces $n \le p$ where $q = p^k$ so you don't gain anything by working with a non-prime field.

Right, it was obvious in retrospect! Thanks.

Suppose $q = p^k$, so your field has characteristic $p$.  From condition (1) we get
$\varphi(j) = j \varphi(1)$ for $1 \le j \le n$, so
in particular $\varphi(p+1) = \varphi(1)$ if $p+1\le 2n$, contradicting (2).  So we need $p \ge 2n$.
On the other hand, if $p \ge 2n$ and $k > 1$, we can take $\varphi(i)$ to be the image of $i$ in $\mathbb F_p \subset \mathbb F_q$.
